# Using XSLT to generate usernames(comparing nodes)

Tags: xml, xslt, duplicates, unique, transformation

Here is my Requirment:

Lastname is the username, if lastname is same use lastname + First initial, if lastname + First initial is same use lastname + First initial+second letter first name.

I have tried using keys but i was not successful.(Input is an XML document with demographic data and may have about 1200 records in total, need to compare the last names from this XML file and generate the username according to the condition as described above).
This is my first question ever, so kindly let me know what info you need to answer.

I can use XSLT 1.0 or 2.0

Here is a sample XML:

```
<XML>
<Data>
        <First_Name>Chris</First_Name>
        <Middle_Name>E</Middle_Name>
        <Last_Name>Kyle</Last_Name>
        <Employee_ID>100</Employee_ID>
</Data>
<Data>
        <First_Name>Allen</First_Name>
        <Middle_Name></Middle_Name>
        <Last_Name>Kyle</Last_Name>
        <Employee_ID>101</Employee_ID>
</Data>
<Data>
        <First_Name>Aron</First_Name>
        <Middle_Name></Middle_Name>
        <Last_Name>Kyle</Last_Name>
        <Employee_ID>102</Employee_ID>
</Data>
<Data>
        <First_Name>Luffy</First_Name>
        <Middle_Name>D</Middle_Name>
        <Last_Name>Monkey</Last_Name>
        <Employee_ID>103</Employee_ID>
</Data>
<XML>
```

For this example after transformation i should get the usernames as follows:
1)Kylec
2)Kyleal
3)Kylear
4)Monkey

Here is my XSLT which partially works(had multiple changes but currently stuck here)

```
   <xsl:template match="/">
            <xsl:call-template name="HeaderRecord"/>

            <xsl:for-each select="//XML/Data[generate-id(.)= generate-id(key('ELN',Last_Name)[1])]">
            <xsl:sort select="Last_Name" order="ascending"/>
            <xsl:for-each select="key('ELN',Last_Name)">

                <xsl:if test="position()=0">
                    <xsl:call-template name="DataRecords"/>
                </xsl:if>

                <xsl:if test="position()=1">
                    <xsl:for-each select="//XML/Data[generate-id(.)= generate-id(key('EFN1',substring(First_Name,1,1))[1])]">
                        <xsl:for-each select="key('EFN1',substring(First_Name,1,1))">
                            <xsl:sort select="First_Name" order="ascending"/>
                            <xsl:if test="position()=0">
                            <xsl:call-template name="DuplicateDataRecords"/>
                            </xsl:if>
                            <xsl:if test="position()=1">
                            <xsl:call-template name="DuplicateDataRecords2"/>
                             </xsl:if>
                         </xsl:for-each>
                      </xsl:for-each>  
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
```

Thanks!!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Sad to say, SO is not a consultancy service. Show what you have done so far, and perhaps people are able to help you out with the final steps.

Comment: Show us a (small) example of the input and the expected output.

Comment: The thing you're going to have to watch out for is to prevent collisions in the case where lastname+initial collides with someone *else's* last name.  For example, you decide that one initial is good enough to distinguish Ed Smyth from John Smyth, but you also have Mary Smythe in your list.

Comment: @bjimba:  That's a good point, for mary the code may send Smythe but also for Ed Smyth which is something i do not want! It probably would be better to have two conditions only, (last name, is same last name then last name +first initial+Second character)

Comment: Perhaps you should rethink the issue, as there is also the possibility of two people having exactly the same name. A much simpler method would check for duplicates only once, and append a random string (or ID) to any found. This is assuming all usernames are assigned at once - not sure what you plan on doing when new users are added.

Answer (score 1):

You could define a separate key for each condition on checking for existing names; so one for the `Last_Name` only, one for `Last_Name` plus first letter of `First_Name`, abd one for `Last_Name` plus first two letters of `First_Name`

```
<xsl:key name="ELN" match="Data" use="Last_Name" />
<xsl:key name="EFN1" match="Data" use="concat(Last_Name, substring(First_Name,1,1))" />
<xsl:key name="EFN2" match="Data" use="concat(Last_Name, substring(First_Name,1,2))" />
```

Then, you could have a template matching `Data` in which there is an `xsl:choose` that tests all of the conditions using the keys in turn.

So, to check this was the first occurrence of the `Last_Name` (and so use the last name as the user name), do this

```
<xsl:when 
     test="generate-id(.)= generate-id(key('ELN',Last_Name)[1])">
```

The next `xsl:when` would test for `Last_Name` + First character of `First_Name`, but it would also have to check this combination is not a valid `Last_Name` anywhere.

```
<xsl:when 
     test="generate-id(.)= generate-id(key('EFN1',concat(Last_Name, substring(First_Name,1,1)))[1])
           and not(key('ELN', concat(Last_Name, substring(First_Name,1,1))))">
```

And similarly for checking the first two characters of `First_Name`

```
<xsl:when 
     test="generate-id(.)= generate-id(key('EFN2',concat(Last_Name, substring(First_Name,1,2)))[1])
           and not(key('EFN1', concat(Last_Name, substring(First_Name,1,2))))
           and not(key('ELN', concat(Last_Name, substring(First_Name,1,2))))">
```

Try this XSLT...

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:key name="ELN" match="Data" use="Last_Name" />
    <xsl:key name="EFN1" match="Data" use="concat(Last_Name, substring(First_Name,1,1))" />
    <xsl:key name="EFN2" match="Data" use="concat(Last_Name, substring(First_Name,1,2))" />

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Data">
        <User_Name>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="generate-id(.)= generate-id(key('ELN',Last_Name)[1])">
                <xsl:value-of select="Last_Name" />
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="generate-id(.)= generate-id(key('EFN1',concat(Last_Name, substring(First_Name,1,1)))[1])
                            and not(key('ELN', concat(Last_Name, substring(First_Name,1,1))))">
                <xsl:value-of select="concat(Last_Name, substring(First_Name,1,1))" />
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="generate-id(.)= generate-id(key('EFN2',concat(Last_Name, substring(First_Name,1,2)))[1])
                            and not(key('EFN1', concat(Last_Name, substring(First_Name,1,2))))
                            and not(key('ELN', concat(Last_Name, substring(First_Name,1,2))))">
                <xsl:value-of select="concat(Last_Name, substring(First_Name,1,2))" />
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:variable name="username" select="concat(Last_Name, substring(First_Name,1,2))" />
                <xsl:value-of select="$username" />
                <xsl:value-of select="count(preceding-sibling::Data[concat(Last_Name, substring(First_Name,1,2)) = $username]) + 1" />
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
        </User_Name>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that in the case of `Last_Name` + first two letters of `First_Name` not being unique, the fall back I have used is to append a number at the end of the user name.